# UICollectionView dynamic data source items adding to the beginning of the collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm making collection view with a dynamic content loading ability. In my case, I'm making calendar. Current date will be in the visible part (after loading). If you scroll up, the older dates will shown and if you scroll down you'll see next dates.

My collection view use standard flow layout. I have 7 cells in a row and 4 visible rows.

I have a problem with adding older dates (e.g. cells that appears if you scroll up). What I'm doing: first I implement scroll view method for detecting scroll event. 
`startOffsetY` is contentOffset.y value set in viewDidLoad. It's not equal to 0 because I set `contentInset`. `upd` is just a flag that means that new update is could be start.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= startOffsetY - 20 && upd {
      calendar.updateDataSource()
   }
}
```

Next, I calculate dates for previous time slice (about 4 weeks, I also tried 1 week) from the first date that is in my data source array.

After that, I calculate indexPath array and make update to collection view:

```
var indexes = [NSIndexPath]()
for n in 1...4  {    
   for i in reverse(1...7) {
      indexes.append(NSIndexPath(forItem: n * 7 - i, inSection: 0))
   }     
}

self.calendarCollectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in

    self.calendarCollectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(indexes)
}, completion: { (finish) -> Void in

    self.upd = true                
})
```

but, I have visible lags when rows added and scrolling is in progress.

I tried different strategies: I used `reloadData()` and it was ideal (on the simulator) and extremely laggy on my iPhone 4S (this was the first time in my experience when simulator was faster than the device). From this point, I figure out, that animation of inserting items might be the problem. I tried to wrap `performBatchUpdates` into the `UIView.performWithoutAnimation` block, but with no luck also.

I'm really looking for some help, I don't looking for a ready made solutions except they work as I describe (scroll up'n'down and load content) and I can look how it works. Once again, scrolling already loaded items is not a problem, the problem is a lagging when content is add at the begging of my data array.

## EDIT

Code provided by @teamnorge in Swift

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
    var offset : CGFloat!

    println(currentOffset)

    /*  0.125 - 1/8,  0.5 - 1/2  */
    if currentOffset < contentHeight * 0.125 {

        offset = contentHeight * 0.125 - currentOffset


        // reload content here

        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: currentOffset + contentHeight * 0.5 + offset - CGFloat(cellHeight))

    }


    /*  0.75 - 6/8,  0.5 - 1/2  */
    if currentOffset > contentHeight * 0.75 {

        offset = currentOffset - contentHeight * 0.75

        // reload content here


        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: currentOffset - contentHeight * 0.5 - offset + CGFloat(cellHeight))

 }
```

It works very nice, but need to play with `contentOffset` `y` formula because right now trick works only when you scroll up. Will fix this tomorrow and add calendar date calculations.

## EDIT 2

reloading data ruins everything in all of my prototypes. Including the one I made previously. Found something that makes lags a bit lower but still very noticeable and totally unacceptable. Here are these things:

- remove autolayout from cell prototype in the storyboard
- add this code to the cell:

  ```
  cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
  cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
  ```

I think that invalidation of the layout results in these lags. So, I maybe I need to make custom flow layout? And if so what recommendations can you give.

Comment: I updated my answer below, skipped this from my original code, but see this is **important**. When you manually set the `contentOffset` you also triggers the `scrollViewDidScroll` event, to prevent this you need to temporary disable your `scrollViewDidScroll` event processing. You can do it by adding, for example, state variable `enableScrollHandling` and change its state `true/false`, and add `if` condition in the beginning of `scrollViewDidScroll` method, see updated code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually the very interesting topic. I'll try to explain the idea I came up with while working on another Calendar app.

In my case it was not a Calendar View but Day View, hours **00:00 - 24:00** listed from top to bottom, so I had `UITableView` and not `UICollectionView` but it's not that important in this case.

The language used was not Swift but Objective-C, so I just try to translate code samples.

Instead of manipulation with the data source I created `UITableView` with the fixed amount of rows, in my case to store exactly two days (48 rows, two days of 24 hours each). You could choose the amount of rows containing in two full screens.

**The important thing is that total amount of rows must be a multiple of 8.**

Then you need a formula to calculate what's the day number for each particular cell based on what's inside the first visible row.

The idea is that `UICollectionView` is in fact `UIScrollView` so when we scroll down or up we can handle the corresponding event and calculate the visible offsets.

To simulate the infinitive scrolling we handle the `scrollViewDidScroll` and check if you just passed the `1/8` of the `UIScrollView` height scrolling up, move your `UIScrollView` to the `1/2` of height plus the exact offset so it moves to the "second screen" smoothly. And back, if you passed the `6/8` of the `UIScrollView` height while scrolling down, move the `UIScrollView` up to `1/2` of its height minus offset.

When you do this you see scrolling indicator jumps up and down which is very confusing so we have to hide it, just put somewhere in `viewDidLoad`:

```
calendarView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
calendarView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
```

where `calendarView` is your `UICollectionView` instance name.

**Here is the code (translated from Objective-C right here, not tried in the real project):**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView_:UIScrollView) {  
    if !enableScrollingHandling {return}
    var currentOffsetX:CGFloat = scrollView_.contentOffset.x  
    var currentOffSetY:CGFloat = scrollView_.contentOffset.y  
    var contentHeight:CGFloat = scrollView_.contentSize.height  
    var offset:CGFloat  

    /*  0.125 - 1/8,  0.5 - 1/2  */
    if currentOffSetY < (contentHeight * 0.125)  {
        enableScrollingHandling = false  
        offset = (contentHeight * 0.125) - currentOffSetY    

        // @todo: your code, specify which days are listed in the first row (2nd screen)

        scrollView_.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: currentOffsetX, y: currentOffset + 
        contentHeight * 0.5 + offset - CGFloat(kRowHeight))

        enableScrollingHandling = true
        return
    }  

    /*  0.75 - 6/8,  0.5 - 1/2  */
    if currentOffSetY > (contentHeight * 0.75)  {  
        enableScrollingHandling = false  
        offset = currentOffSetY - (contentHeight * 0.75)    

        // @todo: your code, specify which days are listed in the first row (1st screen)

        scrollView_.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: currentOffsetX, y: currentOffset - 
        contentHeight * 0.5 - offset + CGFloat(kRowHeight))
        enableScrollingHandling = true
        return
    }  
}
```

Then in your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` based on what's in the first row (is this content of the first screen or second screen) and what are the current visible days (formula) you just update the cell content.

This formula could also be a tricky part and may require some workaround especially if you decide to put Month Names in between months. I do also have some ideas on how to organise it, so if you encounter any problem we can discuss it here.

But such an approach to simulate infinitive scrolling with "two screens loop and jumps in between" works really like a charm, very smooth scrolling like behaviour tested on older phones also.

PS: **kRowHeight** is just a constant the height of the exact row (cell) it's needed for precise and smooth scrolling behaviour it could be skipped I think.

#### UPDATE:

Important notice, I skipped this from original code, but see this is important. When you manually set the `contentOffset` you also triggers the `scrollViewDidScroll` event, to prevent this you need to temporary disable your `scrollViewDidScroll` event processing. You can do it by adding, for example, state variable `enableScrollHandling` and change its state `true/false`, see updated code.

Comment: wow, great answer, I'll prototype it right now, and then write what I get and about the formula, didn't know about such approach:) Thanks for such great post!

Comment: I add information to my question, great approach! :) will finish it tomorrow.

Comment: I wrote you in the chat, I made a prototype, you might be interested.